# The coding outcome is not displayed

Tags: python-3.x

I used to see error on :

```
try:
    datetime.datetime(int(year),int(month),int(day))
except FileNotFoundError:
    if is_valid_date: 
       print('Input date is Valid')
```

Comment: what? is that all of your code? please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour),
read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
and provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
that reproduces your problem.

Comment: why would `datetime` raise a `FileNotFoundError`?!

Comment: This is a very bad code. Why would datetime take 3 args and raise a FileNotFoundError ? What is your purpose